# Maven - How to get the parent pom file dependency in sbt project

Tags: java, scala, maven

Not able to resolve the dependencies of maven project in sbt.Here is my issue,

for example :

> MyProject =>   module1(pom.xml)    ,module2(pom.xml)  , parentPom.xml

After deployment to the artifactory, i have `module1.jar,module2.jar and parentPom.pom` in the artifactory,when i am trying to add the dependency of module1 in my sbt project i am getting the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.test#module1;5.22.0-SNAPSHOT: local-snapshots: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.test#MyProject;5.22.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

Can anyone please help me with this!!

Answer (score 0):

if your `module1.jar` and `module2.jar` is a `mavne` generated jar than go inside jar and fild `pom.xml` file, it may inside `metainf` inside jar, search for pom.xml, and look what is the name of `pom.xml` file inside jar, give the same name in your project pom.xml, if it is not work you can write back to me, can you put your project `pom.xml` and module1.jar`s`pom.xml`

**Edited:**

From the URL you had given in comment is https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/pom.xml
After look that pom.xml file you should try to add in your project pom.xml look like this

add dependency

```
<groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
<artifactId>activiti-root</artifactId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
```

As in above pom.xml it have parent pom so you need that parent pom too in you maven repository.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
  </parent>
```

And you should also ready for internal dependency for activity pom.xml.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
yes,i have gone through the steps that u suggested.in each module jar there is a respective pom file with name as pom.xml. 
 In each pom file there is a dependency of parent pom as :               
     <parent>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
    <version>5.22.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

error is showing like it is not able to find the parent pom.

Comment: is you have added the parent pom in your project pom.xml?, can you try to build module1 and module2 jar without <relativePath>, i think it is searching for path is mention in pom.xml. just remove relative path form each pom.xml and add dependency of parent pom.xml in each pom.xml

Comment: yes i did the same but getting the same issue. ok let me tell you my actual use case:

i have downloaded the activiti source code from https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti 
and published it to my local artifactory.

My actual project is in scala ,i am trying to have dependency of one of the module (activiti-engine) in my project.But getting the issue as unresolved dependency of activiti-root.

Can u pls check this once.